# I want to find good offline android maps for drone navigation

Tags: android, navigation

i'm currently working on my own diy android-controlled drone project. I try to develope navigation function that position drone by its coordinate getting from its gps module: latitude, longititude. It needs map(e.g google map) that can display terrains and drone's position. 
The reason i didn't choose google map is that first, data usage. My phone is already connected to drone's wifi AP. And it is unable to connect to another ap so i have to use cellular data channel. Secondly, my drone doesn't need very much accurate maps like google map. My drone mostly needs road information for routing.  So please recommend me offline android map anf if there's thing that i'm wrong about the reason, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Maps app in offline mode whereby it will save data for areas you choose to the phone when you are on wiFi and you can set google maps to not use cellular data.

Try the link below
https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en